# How did this Vampire's takeoff damage the runway so much?

Tags: jet-engine, runways

This appears to be real, but, what's the cause?

Aircraft is a DeHavilland Vampire on takeoff from a small airfield, but the runway's surface disintegrates from jet blast

Full file at https://i.imgur.com/NaK5yAr.mp4

[image]

Is the Vampire's jet blast that strong?  Or is it weak/old tarmac which is being pushed over the limit of adhesion?

I suspect the field would be closed for repairs becuase of this damage, and the the runway's now lack of smoothness,  but could that plane land again right away?   If the loose bits were picked up?  Would it have to land on the grass verge instead?

Would this have happened with other aircraft on the same runway?  Or is the vampire special?

---

Other info

Plane's registration number is WZ507

https://www.facebook.com/Vampire-WZ507-351376189100/

This airframe is also the poster photo on https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Vampire_3_%28cropped%29_copy.jpg/450px-Vampire_3_%28cropped%29_copy.jpg

Comment: FWIW the [AAIB](https://www.gov.uk/aaib-reports?date_of_occurrence%5Bfrom%5D=29%2F4%2F2017&date_of_occurrence%5Bto%5D=1%2F5%2F2017) reported no such incident on that day, 2017 April 30.  Maybe because the aircraft itself was undamaged.

Answer (score 4):

Partly it's that the Vamp's tail pipe is only a foot above the surface, angled toward it, so with most jets that wouldn't happen quite as easily.  Plus it looks to me like the airport operator cut corners with a really cheap driveway quality paving job with an asphalt layer only an inch or two thick.